# Write-S3Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credentials'

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I’m trying to set up AWS deployment via the AWS Tools for Powershell on a new machine using `write-s3object -credentials $aws_creds ...`, and I’m running into the following error:

```
Write-S3Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credentials'.
```

This has definitely worked for me previously, and the AWS [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/pstoolsref-commonparams.html) still say you should be able to pass through credentials with `-Credentials`. Does anyone know if this behaviour has changed?

Answer (score 2):

Found it - it appears to now be just `-Credential` without the 's'. AWS docs still say `-Credentials`, and unfortunately `Get-Help` doesn’t show the AWS common parameters.